# aws ecs fargate service connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm fairly new to aws. I am trying to deploy two services, frontend and server. On the server, after the users verify registration through email, they will be navigated to frontend page. Therefore, in backend, I need to specify the frontend server ip address like this: "frontend_url = f'http://{frontend_host}:80/login'".
I am trying to use service connect in ecs to resolve dns resolution in the vpc.
[dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRj4L.png)

This is what I get after running the service. I replaced the frontend_host with "frontend" but the dns is not resolved to ip address. It keeps navigating me to "http://frontend/login".
I would appreciate any helps

Comment: Will need more info as to how both services are setup in order to make sense of it.

Comment: Can you provide output of following command for your cluster ?

`aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters your-cluster-name`

Comment: Are you passing that URL to a user's web browser? The DNS lookup isn't going to happen until the browser tries to open the URL, and the user's browser isn't going to be wired up to service connect configured inside your VPC. Service connect is typically used for backend services to find each other, not for front-end URLs.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for pointing this out. I am using front-end URLs so it doesn't work.